# Does SerialPort use polling internally?

Tags: .net, serial-port, vb6

I have no idea how it could work differently, but I would like to ask anyway:

To read data from a serial comm port, I have always used polling.

First, I opened the port by getting a file handle, then I use a timer and read data from the file handle like this:

```
Private Function pReadComm32() As String

    Dim RetBytes As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ReadStr As String
    Dim bRead(256) As Byte
    Dim RetVal As Long
    RetVal = ReadFile(m_lTextFileHandle, bRead(0), 256, RetBytes, 0)
    ReadStr = ""
    If (RetBytes > 0) Then  
    For i = 0 To RetBytes - 1
        ReadStr = ReadStr & VBA.Chr(bRead(i))
    Next i

    pReadComm32 = ReadStr

End Function
```

Now when I port my project from VB6 to VB.NET, I would like to use the SerialPort component instead.

It provides the OnDataReceived events.

I would like to know how this component works internally.
Does it do the very same under the hood as my code does and also uses polling?

This is a question out of interest, not a real problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps a boot program might use polling (and PIO) during the very early stages of system bring-up. But for a modern OS, no polling of HW, and interrupts would be used by device drivers for efficiency.  DMA, though, might be optional. However there are typically several layers of software for what you call a "*serial port*".  Your userspace program "reads" from a system buffer, rather than any hardware registers.  E.G. see diagram at the end of [Linux serial drivers](https://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html) to get an idea of how separated your code can be from the HW.

Comment: How about looking at the source code around here? [runtime/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialPort.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialPort.cs)

Comment: Both SerialPort in .Net and MSCOMM32.OCX in VB6 use a separate thread for their respective DataReceived events. You can keep using ReadFile API function in .Net if you do not want to refactor your polling code.